# What's the proper way to add javascript inside jQuery's $(document).ready with Yii

Tags: jquery, yii

I'm using Yii framework. On a couple of pages I want to add some custom UI stuff using jQuery. I want the result to be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     ... my code
});
```

I found advice to use something like this:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('testscript',"
    alert('hello world');
",CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

However, I have a rather large javascript code (about 100 lines) and it's hard to even read it when it's inside PHP string (no syntax highlighting in editor, no code folding).

There must be some better way to do it?

I wouldn't mind even placing the code in separate .js file, but I have no clue how to load it in to document.ready handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isolate your code into a class/function in a JS file, register that with registerScriptFile, then invoke that class / method with registerScript (will then be added to the ready-method which CClientScript uses.

Comment: Nice and clean solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've never used yii, but searching around on Google I've found that you can add javascript to yii.

I'm a .net guy, but this link may help you out.
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/4778-what-is-the-best-form-to-load-jquery/

I'm just guessing but it'll probably look like this...

```
 Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('/myScript.js');
```

And in myScript.js you'd write...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hi'); 
    //js code goes here
 });
```

Now I'm just guessing, but you'd probably have to include the jquery plugin before any of this. So, its probably something like ...

(PHP)

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile('/myScript.js'); ?>
```

(JQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hi'); //script goes here
 });
```

Comment: This is exactly the reason I'm asking. If I do it like you propose I end up having two document.ready sections. One in HTML and another in external javascript file.

Comment: I don't understand why would you have `document.ready` in HTML, just put all javascript code in the external file. In any case, multiple `document.ready` will work just fine, they will all run after the DOM is ready in first-come first-served order.

Comment: Yii automatically adds document.ready() in HTML for other stuff that it handles automatically like client-side validation, etc.

Comment: Well, it seems that multiple document.ready are really not a problem. They are stacked as dakis suggest, so I'll accept this answer although I wish there was a nicer solution. I was hoping to be able to write a separate .js file and then include it inside Yii's document.ready section, but it seems that is not possible.